# ClickOnce Silent installation

Tags: parameters, registry, vsto, clickonce, silent-installer

I'm looking for a possibility to install ClickOnce applications silent. I already read like a million of threads but nothing helped. I tried VSTO, Copying the files and registry keys, silent parameters...

Is it possible to hide the window or just the prompt on which you have to press Yes or No to install?

I don't care about the kind, just share with me please

Answer (score 0):

Click once deployment is the best solution and choose the option 
Application should check for updates after the application starts[image]

Comment: I don't have the source of the application. My company want me to package it. So I think I cannot use your method, thx anyways.